# How to get a content from Windows Phone webview control

Tags: windows-phone-8, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to get a DOM model from webview control or just HTML to process it by XML tools. That control does not offer any property which returns what I need. I have found a solution by using JS:

```
string html = Browser1.InvokeScript("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
```

But I am getting a not implemented exception.

What am I doing wrong? I'm new in WP programming.

Comment: Have you tried `InvokeScriptAsync`? As [written here:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescript.aspx) *InvokeScript may be altered or unavailable for releases after Windows 8.1. Instead, use InvokeScriptAsync.* Also please check if you are running *Silverlight* or *WinRT* -> *InvokeScript **=** Windows Runtime apps only*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Like Romasz said use InvokeScriptAsync -- but make sure the page is loaded first.

Sample Application:

```XAML
<Grid>        
    <StackPanel>
        <WebView x:Name="myWebView" Height="300" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Content="Read HTML" Click="Button_Click" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```C#
    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.myWebView.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string html = await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
            myTextBlock.Text = html;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it helped. I missed that change for WP 8.1.

Comment: @JarosławSzczepaniak np, can you mark it as a solution?  And welcome to SO :)

Comment: and to pick up the document inner text?