# Find a Text / String in a WebView of windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a local html file opened in the WebView, here I need to search a Text from the webview. Android has  `webview.findAll(string);` & `webview.findAllAsync(string);` methods to achieve this.

Is there any method or alternative to do the same in windows phone 8.1??

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347363/how-to-get-a-content-from-windows-phone-webview-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string html = await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
if(html.Contains("Your text")){
    //text available in the web page
}
```

Or you can use `html.indexOf("Text")` method if you want to get the location instead.

Comment: Does this method works with only Windows phone 8.1...? Or it worked with wp8.1 Silverlight only??