# Get Source Code from Webview (VB for Metro)

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, windows-8, webview

I'm Making a Windows Phone's app that I can, From a webview called "DebWeb", get the ClassRoom of a specific class. The DebWeb load the site where is all the classRooms, but I want to make that my App search just my class.

Before I made an app with almost the same objetive (search the Name of a App from the Source Code), but it was made from VB for PC, now I'm working on VB for Metro (or for App Store) and I can't use the same code.

For example, On VB for PC I can use:

```
Dim EHTML = DebWeb.Document.All.Item(1)
Dim sourceString As String = EHTML.InnerHtml
'Use Regex Match to search from SourceString"
```

But on VB for Metro it's shows me the " 'Document' is not a member of 'Windows.UI.XAML.Controls.WebView' " error, so I can't get the Source Code from the page and I can't look for the ClassRoom.

I Looked on the MSDN page about Webview but the most close thing that I can do is to get the "DocumentTittle", but not the content.

This is my code, everything "works" except the "Source" variable:

```
    Dim Source = DebWeb.[Control] 'Here is where I need the Control to get the SourceCode
    Dim m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Source.ToString, _
    "DERECHO CONSTITUCIONAL", _
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Edited with my Entire code:

```
Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded

    Dim URL As String = "http://goo.gl/uqohKw"
    Me.DebWeb.Navigate(New Uri(URL))
End Sub

Private Sub DebWeb_LoadCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs)
    LListo.Text = "Listo!"
    Dim html As String = DebWeb.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", New String() {"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"}).ToString
    Dim Source = html
    Dim m As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(Source.ToString, _
    "LECTURA CRÍTICA", _
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    If (m.Success) Then
        Dim key As String = m.Groups(1).Value

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347363/how-to-get-a-content-from-windows-phone-webview-control

Comment: Thanks but I tried it Before, I get error on "new string[]" (Identifier Expected) and on "Regex.Match(Source" (Source is not declared, what the...), maybe because it's a C# code and I'm working on VB (Please note that I still Sudying VB, I don't know anything from C# for now)

Comment: Maybe change `New String[]` to `New String()`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    Try
        Dim html As String = Await myWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", New String() {"document.documentElement.outerHTML;"})
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

More Info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: If MyTextBlock.Text shows the Source Code (HTML) from the X webPage, then yes, but, I get this on "source Variable": {Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation(Of String)}, and Match couldn't find "Derecho constitucional" (The class room)

Comment: Instead of using `Dim Source = DebWeb.[Control]` use `Dim Source = html`

Comment: Tried it but "Await Can only use can only be used when contained within a method or lambda expression marked with the 'Async' modifier.". If I delete Await, Source and html is now "System.__ComObject"

Comment: Can you not mark the Button_Click as an async method?